# Errors when using the URI class to connect to a website

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to connect the url below. This works fine but the application crashes after execution, any ideas? Logcat complains about line 77 - `connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.getContent();` which I changed from `connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();` as the url wasn't being executed. This code is executed within a button onClick Listener. Thanks in advance.

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://apps.smilemachine.com/smilefactory/api/v1.0/speedup");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    connection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Log cat output:

11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at com.developer.machine.Screen1$1.onClick(Screen1.java:81)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 22:11:21.153: E/AndroidRuntime(2676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Are you running this from the UI thread? Also, please post the Logcat output.

Comment: I have posted the logcat output and I'm not too sure about which thread its being executed on??

Comment: Change your code back to `connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();` and post the Logcat output. Or, don't expect to get a `HttpURLConnection` from `getContent()`, that method actually should return an `InputStream`.

Comment: Really, the [documentation for HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) has a good example of this. Just make sure to not execute this stuff on the UI thread.